# Is the intersection of a bunch of cylinders a sphere?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Suppose we have a 3-D shape $S$ with a center $C$, so that a point $p$ is in $S$ if and only if for any direction $\vec d$, $p$ is contained within a cylinder of radius $1$, extending infinitely both ways in the direction $\vec d$ and with its axis passing through $C$.

Is the resulting shape a sphere of radius $1$?

Comment: I expect that the answer is "yes", but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you’ve seen that the sphere of radius $1$ is contained in every such cylinder, I’ll give you this hint: consider a point $P$ that's *not* in the unit sphere. Can’t you find one of your cylinders that similarly doesn’t contain $P$?

To focus your mind, you might coordinatize lightly, putting your center $C$ at the origin of Cartesian $3$-space. And permit yourself to choose your bad point with very good coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, it was simple.

Comment: (This wasn't homework, by the way. I'm not even in class for a while; the question just popped up.)

Comment: It’s a natural question to wonder about.